# Selenium alternative for waitForPageToLoad when dealing with AJAX-type operation

Tags: ajax, selenium, command

I am running some unit tests on my code, and for this I had to download the selenium server. Now, one of the examples selenium includes is called GoogleTest. I had this copied to my C:\ folder, and tried to run it.

At first, i had an error trying to open firefox. Seems that selenium hasn't been updated for quite some time, since it supports up till Firefox version 3.5. Found [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/thomasweller/archive/2010/02/14/making-selenium-1.0.1-work-with-firefox-3.6.aspx) helpful blog that helped me (changing 3.5.* for 7.0.*).

Now, I have a new problem. It seems selenium hasn't updated its docs either, and the GoogleTest hangs when executed ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652235/selenium-rc-waitforpagetoload-hangs) post explains why). When using AJAX type operations, the operation waitForPageToLoad hangs.

Now, I need an equivalent to this operation but when dealing with AJAX operations.. anybody knows of an alternative? Thanks

Comment: Which version of selenium are you using? Surely, 2.0 does not have this issue. If you are looking for alternatives, have you checked out Sahi?

Comment: After this I decided to check my Selenium version. I was convinced I has the latest release, but my version.txt doc says otherwise (selenium.rc.version=1.0.1). I'll try downloading the latest one and see if it works. Thanks!

Comment: I ran into some problems trying to use selenium 2.0 version, I posted another question here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947773/running-tests-with-nunit-and-selenium-2-11-0-exception). If you could help me out with that, great!

Answer (score 2):

Did you tried with [QAF formerly ISFW](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/)? It internally waits for element as well as provides wait functionality for ajax to complete for may of the js toolkit like dojo, extjs, prototype etc

for example if the AUT uses extjs then you can use like

```
waitService.waitForAjaxToComplete(JsToolkit.EXTJS);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no waitforajaxtoreturn function in Selenium. The way AJAX changes are handled are by using the `WebDriverWait` class to wait for a specific condition to become true when the AJAX call returns.

So for example, for the Google test, the `WebDriverWait` could wait for the search container to appear.

In essence, you have to know what you are waiting for in order to continue the test.

Answer (score 0):

I am testing some ajax and JS heavy pages and I have been facing exactly the same problem. I have used implicit waits to to pause for the ajax code to execute and load the new content to DOM . Here is a python sample from my code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
browserHandle = webdriver.Firefox()
browserHandle.implicitly_wait(10)
## assuming dom object loads in 10 seconds
## clear implicit wait
browserHandle.implicitly_wait(0)
```