# Running tests with NUnit and Selenium 2.11.0 exception

Tags: unit-testing, selenium, nunit

I'm trying to run some tests in C# with NUnit and Selenium 2. Steps I followed:

- I installed NUnit. I figure I can't have any errors here.
- I downloaded Selenium 2: I got the client from [this](http://selenium.googlecode.com/files/selenium-dotnet-2.11.0.zip) link and the C# server from [this](http://selenium.googlecode.com/files/selenium-server-standalone-2.11.0.jar) one.
- Started the selenium server executing the following command: (i´m now doubting whether this step is necessary or not)

  ```
  java -jar C:\selenium-remote-control-2.11.0\selenium-server-2.11.0\selenium-2.11.0\selenium-server-standalone-2.11.0.jar
  ```

When -using NUnit- I run a simple google test which uses an instance of FirefoxDriver, this error comes up:

```
SeleniumTests.Test (TestFixtureSetUp):
SetUp : System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception : The system cannot find the file specified
at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.Internal.Executable.LocateFirefoxBinaryFromPlatform() in c:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\dotnet\src\WebDriver\Firefox\Internal\Executable.cs:line 197
at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.Internal.Executable..ctor(String userSpecifiedBinaryPath) in c:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\dotnet\src\WebDriver\Firefox\Internal\Executable.cs:line 36
at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxBinary..ctor(String pathToFirefoxBinary) in c:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\dotnet\src\WebDriver\Firefox\FirefoxBinary.cs:line 66
at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver..ctor() in c:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\dotnet\src\WebDriver\Firefox\FirefoxDriver.cs:line 114
at SeleniumTests.Test.FixtureSetup() in c:\users\julio\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\UnitTestingElSuperDT\UnitTestingElSuperDT\Test.cs:line 18
```

This is driving me crazy!! Any help out there?

Answer (score 1):

First things first, to run test with selenium using C#.NET you don't have to use the RC(remote control) server.  All you need to do is

```
public IWebDriver driver = new FireFoxDriver();

public void test()
{
  driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("google.com");
}
```

as to your error.  I had a similar problem and I want to say that it had something to do with the port that RC Server runs on on your local computer.

------- Edit -------

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox; //needed to open the firefox driver

namespace SeleniumBenchmark
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static IWebDriver browserDriver = new FirefoxDriver();  //instantiates the webdriver (opens the browser)

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            browserDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://yahoo.com"); //navigates to the page
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in truth I don't remember what I did because I stopped using RC.  Since you only need RC to run JavaScript, and I found a way to do what I wanted without JavaScript.

Comment: would you mind me asking what way did you find? Because I am really running out of options!

Comment: @Soph I am using VS2010 IDE.  If you have VS go to the package manager console and type in Install-Package Selenium.Support and that will install everything you need. If not then all you have to do is install your references with your IDE.  You need to have Selenium, Selenium Support, Castle.Core, Newtonsoft.Json to get the most out of Webdriver.  However just downloading the Webdriver.dll and referencing that in your IDE and then instantiating your IWebDriver should be enough to open a browser.  See the edits above.